# Problems with camera in flutter app (The selected imageFormatGroup is not supported by > Android. Defaulting to yuv420)

Tags: flutter, dart, camera

I have problems with integration of a photography function in my app.
I get asked if I permit the access to the camera, but after that nothing happens exept this errror:

> W/Camera  (26849): The selected imageFormatGroup is not supported by
> Android. Defaulting to yuv420
>
> I/CameraManagerGlobal(26849): Camera 0 facing CAMERA_FACING_BACK state
> now CAMERA_STATE_OPEN for client...

This is my code:

```
class FaultReporting extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _FaultReportingState createState()=> _FaultReportingState();
}

class _FaultReportingState extends State<FaultReporting>{
  bool isReady=false;
  List<CameraDescription> cameras;
  CameraController camController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    setupCameras();
  }

  Future<void> setupCameras() async {
    try {
      cameras = await availableCameras();
      camController = new CameraController(cameras[0], ResolutionPreset.medium);
      await camController.initialize();
    } on CameraException catch (_) {
      setState(() {
        isReady = false;
      });
    }
    setState(() {
      isReady = true;
    });
  }

...

child: ElevatedButton(
                                onPressed: (){
                                  if(!isReady && !camController.value.isInitialized)
                                    {
                                      return Container();
                                    }
                                    return AspectRatio(
                                      aspectRatio: camController.value.aspectRatio,
                                      child: CameraPreview(camController),
                                    );
                                },
...
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had the exact same error when I used the camera on flutter. The message is just informing you that the imageFormatGroup parameter must be ImageFormatGroup.yuv420.
So try this:

```
camController = new CameraController(
    cameras[0],
    ResolutionPreset.medium,
    imageFormatGroup: ImageFormatGroup.yuv420,
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. However, the abovementioned solution (adding imageFormatGroup: ImageFormatGroup.yuv420) did not solve the problem.

I found out what was the real problem. Turns out Flutter Navigation requires pushed routes to be popped before another one pushed into navigator.

Otherwise, it will cause big issues with all camera using packages (CameraController from camera, QRViewController? controller from qr_code_scanner, MobileScannerController cameraController from mobile_scanner all affected) using packages (Both Android and iOS), specially if you use your own custom internal navigation without using Flutter Navigator.

Because, that way you use Navigator partially and in some situations you push several different routes without popping them or even pushing same route several times.

The camera will come either black or keep loading forever. Only thing will solve the issue is to kill/force stop the app and open again as it clears Flutter Navigator.

In Android you will see this error: `"MessageQueue: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Handler sending message to a Handler on a dead thread"`

In iOS you will see this: `"The selected imageFormatGroup is not supported by iOS. Defaulting to brga8888"`

Another related error from mobile_scanner package: `flutter: MobileScanner: Called start() while already started!`

Realted error from qr_code_scanner package: `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Scan rect cannot be set when not (yet) scanning. You may want to set it within didStartScanningBlock.`

Here is the solution which may help you to prevent it. What we need to do is to make sure that when we push new route to the Navigator we are clearing other previously pushed routes from it:

For undefined routes:

```
Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
                                          MaterialPageRoute(
                                              builder: (context) => YourPage()),
                                          (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
```

For defined routes:

```
Navigator.of(context)
    .pushNamedAndRemoveUntil('/yourdefinedroute', (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
```